# Obtaining MSISDN for a Symbian client

Tags: java, java-me, symbian, wap, msisdn

I need to obtain MSISDN for authentication.Doing authentication by any another way,is not an option.

I can summarize my research until now  as follows:

1.There is no API to obtain MSISDN on J2ME.

2.One method to obtain the MSISDN is to obtain it when an HTTP request is made from the device,since the MSISDN no is sent in an HTTP header.This is not a reliable method,because some service providers do not send the MSISDN no.Also if the request is obtained without passing through the WAP gateway,MSISDN will not be obtained.I have read the HTTP headers(using PHP script) from the concerned service provider and I can confirm that there is no MSISDN no present in the headers.

My doubts are:

1.The product is for a telco service provider.Is there anything we can do to make them include MSISDN no in the header if it is not there?

2.What should happen after MSISDN is recieved during installation?I read some where that changes to the JAD file must be made before download.

3.Are there any other methods for obtaining the MSISDN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the information to included in the headers it is totally dependent upon the operators and my experience atleast here in the UK that none of them do. So there is no guarantee that the number will always be there.

There can be a compromise  or a work around, since the user is  making an http connection to your server you can ask them to enter their number in a form field. Upon receiving that number you send an SMS with a key code which they need to enter on the same web page for the installation to work. I know not exactly what you want but atleast you have some sort of verification that the user is who he/she claims to be. Once you have received the correct keycode back you can modify your jad attributes accordingly before progressing with install.

Comment: Thank you Orlymee.Can we some how make the telco add the MSISDN header to the request for that particular domain name(which is a domain name belonging to that same telco)? I just want to know if it is technically possible.

Comment: You will need to approach all the service providers since the users can come from any network. I would that these sort of partnerships will come at a cost but I have never done one myself so cannot comment. There is no harm in speaking to the right people. You have to keep in mind that operators want to maintain the privacy of the user hence they do not forward that information.

Comment: In my experience (errors aside!!!  http://bit.ly/NnWTbr) having the MSISDN included in your visitors' HTTP headers involves being placed on a special whitelist...  this only happens for a very select few approved applications.  This process, again in my experience with UK operators, tends to be glacial.

Comment: @funkybro..We have a contract with the said service provider via another party.So that should be possible.Also it is not at all necessary for us to run that app via other service providers' access points.+1 for this info.

Answer (score 0):

There was opened internal API when Symbian became OSS some time ago, it can be found in full sources of Symbian OS. Since it's platform dependent, there is no guarantee that compiled for some SDK it will work on target phones.